# JQL - Multiple search for keyword in comment

Tags: jira, jql

Need to find a JQL query to search for the keyword "urgent" which was commented by the reporter, but note that this keyword is being used in a default response in comments (i.e. "let us know if this is urgent").

For example, if the ticket contains Comment 2 below, then it should show in the results of the query since it has the "urgent" keyword which is not on the default response.

> Comment 1: "Please let us know if this is urgent."
>   Comment 2: "This is urgent."

However, if the keyword is only found on the default response, then it should not show in the results.

Let me know if this is possible to do!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have better responses to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tasking to get in a JQL , but possible with API and customisations with JIRA.
You want to analyse the body of a comment with some conditions too., its best to go with API for such activity.

JQL is best suited for Simple query which have structured data and values-- JQL is more like a filter (Advanced Filter)